# Does multiplying Taylor series by an integer change the interval of validity.

Tags: taylor-expansion

If I have a Taylor series for example,

> $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \ldots, \qquad \text{valid for $-1<x<1$} $

and I multiply the series by some integer, let's say $5$, in order to get $\frac{5}{1-x}$ would it affect the interval of validity or would the series still be valid for any x between $(-1,1)$?

Comment: There is no change (unless the integer is $0$)

Comment: I presume same goes for fractions? I should have mention that in the question as well.

Comment: @Pawel Any non-zero number that multiplies a series doesn't change at all its convergence radius. If the number is zero the radius automatically become infinity.

Comment: Indeed this answers my question. Could you post your comment as an answer so I could mark it as closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Henry and @Joanpemo said in comments; when I multiply a series by any non-zero number it does not change the interval of validity of the series.